# How to correct for selection bias caused by a prior version of a logistic GLM?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, bias, regression-strategies

I've looked for information on this, but there are a lot of different angles to addressing selection bias I'm lost on how to proceed.

Here is the basic scenario:

1. We collect data on *n* customers.
2. Of those n customers, we follow up with on a certain number *n_followup* for additional screening. The decision of whether or not to follow up is based on a logistic regression with known parameters.
3. We want to re-estimate the model with a newer dataset, and possibly add new variables as well. Changing the model specification is also on the table.

I think I intuitively see the issue here -- just rerunning the model on *n_followup* is going to produce biased estimates, since we'd expect the previous model to have some predictive power. Is there a good way to correct this, either in the context of a GLM or better yet in general? Would some sort of weighting by the relative frequency in *n_followup* compared to *n* work? If I need to make some strong distributional assumptions that's fine.

Thanks, I appreciate the help!